# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: SimpleTable (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM SimpleTable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

> I have tried all of the solutions I could find and still haven't been able to get around this error. The error occurs in the getNotes() section, in its forth line. Also, the getNote() is currently not doing anything, so you don't need to look at that. I directly copied all code from these youtube tutorials, which I then adapted to my needs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pa_lghjVQVA&t=933s

> Thanks for any help.

````
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NoteDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SimpleDB";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "SimpleTable";

    //nome das colunas da tabela
    private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    private static final String KEY_STARS = "stars";
    private static final String KEY_OPENING_HOURS_1 = "opening_hours_1";
    private static final String KEY_OPENING_HOURS_2 = "opening_hours_2";
    private static final String KEY_OPENING_HOURS_3 = "opening_hours_3";
    private static final String KEY_NOTAS = "notas";

    public NoteDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createDB = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                KEY_TITLE + "TEXT," +
                KEY_LOCATION + "TEXT," +
                KEY_STARS + "TEXT," +
                KEY_OPENING_HOURS_1 + "TEXT," +
                KEY_OPENING_HOURS_2 + "TEXT," +
                KEY_OPENING_HOURS_3 + "TEXT," +
                KEY_NOTAS + "TEXT" + " )";
        db.execSQL(createDB);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion >= newVersion)
            return;
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public long addNote(Note note) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put(KEY_TITLE, note.getTitle());
        v.put(KEY_LOCATION, note.getLocation());
        v.put(KEY_STARS, note.getStars());
        v.put(KEY_OPENING_HOURS_1, note.getOpening_hours_1());
        v.put(KEY_OPENING_HOURS_2, note.getOpening_hours_2());
        v.put(KEY_OPENING_HOURS_3, note.getOpening_hours_3());
        v.put(KEY_NOTAS, note.getNotas());

        long ID = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, v);
        Log.d("Inserted", "ID ->" + ID);
        return ID;
    }

    public Note getNote(long id) {
        //select * from database table where id=1
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] query = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_STARS,
                KEY_OPENING_HOURS_1, KEY_OPENING_HOURS_2, KEY_OPENING_HOURS_3, KEY_NOTAS};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, query, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        return new Note(cursor.getLong(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6),
                cursor.getString(7));
    }



     public List<Note> getNotes() {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
         List<Note> allNotes = new ArrayList<>();
         //select from databaseName
         String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
                 Note note = new Note();
                 note.setID(cursor.getLong(0));
                 note.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                 note.setLocation(cursor.getString(2));
                 note.setStars(cursor.getString(3));
                 note.setOpening_hours_1(cursor.getString(4));
                 note.setOpening_hours_2(cursor.getString(5));
                 note.setOpening_hours_3(cursor.getString(6));
                 note.setNotas(cursor.getString(7));

                 allNotes.add(note);

             } while (cursor.moveToNext());
         }

         return allNotes;
     }

}```
````

Comment: Oh, by the way, when running the debugger in android studio, he is only able to call an error ever other try. Nonetheless, the app still closes on start in every attempt.

Comment: Have you considered using https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room for local databases?  You might find this simplifies database interactions considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you had been following the video which builds up the Database handling step by step.

I have taken your code, added a Note class so it will compile and played around with it a bit. The code itself works fine, however you had (probably do to incremental changes of the code) deleted the table and it has not been recreated yet. Therefore it will always lead to a crash.

Fortunately this can be solved very easily by:

- Either reinstalling the App
- Or by incrementing the Database version

If you choose to delete and install the App again, you can reset the Database version to 1.

If you choose to increment the Database version, `onUpgrade` will be called which will delete the table (if it exists) and then recreate it (by calling `onCreate`).

As someone already mentioned as a comment, SQL should be handled on Android by using `Room` nowadays. I understand you are probably just starting out, but once you get better you should definitely check out Room. It makes things a LOT easier.

Hope this solves your issue :)

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution worked fine. I give it a go at Room, given your sugestions.